# EMS MySQL Manager Migration

Tags: mysql, migration, ems

I have been using EMS MySQL Manager for a while now, however my system died last week and I have since had to transfer anything I can get my hands on to a new machine.

EMS is giving me problems though, I can't for the life of me work out where the usernames and passwords are stored and I could really do with not having to register 60-70 DB's again.

Does anyone know where the application data is stored and how I can transfer it to my new machine?

Thanks!

Comment: If I remember correctly, unfortunately it's in a registry file. I found it a long while ago and successfully migrated settings from one computer to another, let me see if I can find where it was...

Comment: Ah! That would probably make a lot of sense, if you can find it that would be awesome! :D

Comment: See my answer below. Hope this helps..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is saved in the registry under:

`HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\EMS\MySQL Manager\Repository\Databases`

Here is a sample DB configuration:

```
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\EMS\MySQL Manager\Repository\Databases\Item2]
"Alias"="db alias"
"Cached"="False"
"Host"="yourHost"
"LoginPrompt"="False"
"Login"="yourUserName"
"Password"="yourPass"
"Port"="3306"
"Name"="DBName"
"SSL"="False"
"Compress"="False"
"Interactive"="False"
"HttpProxy"="http://webserver_name/emsproxy.php"
"ClientCharset"=""
"DBConnectionType"="dbctDirect"
"MetaDir"=""
"ExportDir"=""
"ImportDir"=""
"ExportLastDir"=""
"ImportLastDir"=""
"HTMLDir"=""
"BackupDir"=""
"ReportDir"="C:\\Users\\yourUserName\\Documents\\SQL Manager 2005 for MySQL\\Reports\\db alias\\"
"MetaLog"="False"
"MetaLogFile"=""
"MetaLogSuccessOnly"="True"
"SQLLog"="False"
"SQLLogFile"=""
"UseTransactions"="True"
"AutoConnect"="False"
"DBFontCharset"="dfcDEFAULT_CHARSET"
"AutoCommit"="False"
"UseQuotes"="False"
"KeepAlive"="False"
"TreeHiddenObjs"=""
"SSHLogin"=""
"SSHPassword"=""
"SSHHost"=""
"SSHPort"=dword:00000016
```

Comment: Thanks for this! Turns out it's not so straightforward to extract this stuff! Long day ahead of me!

Answer (score 5):

No Need to have a long day.  Just Right Click on "`Databases`" to Export the

```
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\EMS\MySQL Manager\Repository\Databases]
```

node and then re-import it (FILE > IMPORT in `REGEDIT`) on your new PC.  It will copy itself into the right place.

Simple!